# how can I access iphone videos programitaclly

Tags: iphone

suppose i load videos to an iPhone using iTunes.
I want to write an app that will allow the selection of videos, and the playing of them.

I am familiar  with the MPMoviePlayerController class. but i only played video that i loaded onside my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't let you access the movies of the iPod application. You can only access audio files.

From the docs

> Use it to find and play user-installed
>   audio-based media items synced from a
>   user’s iTunes library. iPod library
>   access is read-only.

[Link](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006952)